# Trouble decoding base64 in .txt file

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, base64

How do I decrypt or read my base64 `.txt` file in Java?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BaseDec {

     public static void main (String[]args)throws IOException{
        System.out.print("Enter the file name with extension:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        File GuionFile = new File(sc.nextLine());
        sc = new Scanner(File);
        String GuionLine = sc.nextLine();

        byte[] decodedArr = Base64.getDecoder().decode(File);
        String decodedText = new String(decodedArr);

        System.out.println(decodedText);
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Presumably with `Base64.getDecoder()`, if you encode with `Base64.getEncoder()`. What have you tried? Where is it failing?

Comment: Note: base64 is not an encryption format - so decoding it is not called "decryption", just "decoding". Storing "secret" information in base64 adds very little security - it only ensures that people who don't *want* to see secret information don't accidentally see it.

Comment: not yet. i dont know how to do it o.o

Comment: i updated my code please help

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works in JShell:

```
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.Base64;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;

File file = new File("base64test.txt");
System.out.println(new String(Base64.decodeBase64(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()))));
```